# concatenating multiple rows in 1 element separated by "," in R

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a data like this:

```
    date      id      product
29-01-16    1       a
29-01-16    1       b
29-01-16    1       c
```

I have created uniq_id as `id_date`. I want the output like

```
uniq_id       products
1_29-01-16    a,b,c
```

Comment: The number of time this question has been asked and either answered or marked as a duplicate must be at least 10. Yeah, that's a pretty good dupe.

Comment: I think this Q&A is worth linking to as well, as it contains some additional alternatives: [Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w)