# How to show all the values in each level in r?

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data-set that looks like this :

```
first <- c(5:14)
second <- rep(c("a","b"),5)
c <- cbind(first, second)
c
    first second  
 [1,] "5"  "a"
 [2,] "6"  "b"
 [3,] "7"  "a"
 [4,] "8"  "b"
 [5,] "9"  "a"
 [6,] "10" "b"
 [7,] "11" "a"
 [8,] "12" "b"
 [9,] "13" "a"
[10,] "14" "b"
```

As you can see, there are two levels (a and b) 
I want to make a summary that shows what kind of values are in each level.

```
a : 5,7,9,11,13
b : 6,8,10,12,14
```

Comment: something like `c[which(c[,2]=="a"),1]` `c[which(c[,2]=="b"),1]`

Comment: like `split(c[, "a"], c[, "b"])` ? (or just `split(a, b)` actually in your example case)

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple value for each level" ? Is good for you to have a list with 2 entries named "a","b" and each one of them with a vector of values ?

Comment: @lmo yes, works the same as using the columns' names, or just using the vectors `a` and `b` that were defined prior to the matrix `c`

Comment: to make this question clearer: you could indicate how the first column is relevant, or remove it; and could you use different column names vs. data values, or does it matter that they are both `a` and `b`?

Comment: Don't use `cbind` here. Use `c <- data.frame(a,b)`.

Comment: Other alternatives:
by(first, second,c)
or
aggregate(first, list(second),c), where c is not Roland's definition but the function c()

Comment: can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/4137985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has created a matrix with 2 columns. This needs to be converted to data.frame or data.table first before applying one of the many solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w).

```
# create matrix the way the OP has done it but using a different name 
# in order to avoid name conflicts with the c() function
first <- c(5:14)
second <- rep(c("a", "b"), 5)
mat <- cbind(first, second)

# one possible approach
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mat)[, .(first = toString(unique(first))), by = second]
```

> ```
>    second            first
> 1:      a  5, 7, 9, 11, 13
> 2:      b 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
> ```

Note that the use of `unique()` was motivated by the OP's request to show *what **kind of values** are in each level* (emphasis mine).

Comment: Alternately, if they want to do some analysis with the values instead of just browsing them, they could use `list` instead of `toString`, I guess.