# R leaflet map: Include multiple rows of data in label popup

Tags: r, leaflet

I have rows of data with duplicate lat/longs and I want to include a label that has all of the grouped column data.

```
# Make sample dataframe
long <- c(147.5, 147.5, 147.5, 147, 147)
lat <- c(-36.5, -36.5, -36.5, -36, -36)
label <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)

markers <- data.frame(lat,long,label)

# Combine labels based on lat long
markers <- markers %>%
  group_by(lat, long) %>%
  summarize(concat_label = toString(label)) 

# Markers with all of the labels
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  addMarkers(lng=markers$long, lat= markers$lat, 
             popup= markers$concat_label
  )
```

Is there a version of toString that uses a line break instead of a comma? I tried to use paste and paste0 but wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Make sample dataframe
long <- c(147.5, 147.5, 147.5, 147, 147)
lat <- c(-36.5, -36.5, -36.5, -36, -36)
label <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)

markers <- data.frame(lat,long,label)

# Aggregate method
markers <- aggregate(label ~ lat + long, markers, paste, collapse = "<br/>")

# Markers with all of the labels
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  addMarkers(lng=markers$long, lat= markers$lat, 
             popup= markers$label
  )
```

This question had the answer: 
[Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Your label variable can be an HTML string, so you can make the labels stack on each other with a `<br/>` tag. For example:

```
library(leaflet)

long <- c(147.768, 147.768, 147.768,147.768, 147.768, 147.768)
lat <- c(-36.852, -36.852, -36.852,-36.852, -36.852, -36.852)
label <- paste(sep = "<br/>",'long label1', 'long label2', 'long label3','long label4', 'long label5', 'long label6')

markers <- data.frame(lat,long,label)


leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  addMarkers(lng=markers$long, lat= markers$lat, 
             popup=markers$label,
  )
```

[image]

You can also feed variables into the labels using the same approach - concatenating line-by-line.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the structure of the underlying dataframe?  I have many lat/longs so don't want to manually create the labels for each lat/long.

Comment: My example used the sample data frame you provided but you don't need to manually create the labels for each lat/long. Leaflet's `addMarkers` adds markers row by row, so its easy to generate individual markers and labels dynamically for each row - just use variables for the strings you are concatenating. For example: say you have for each observation with a lat/long variables that also describe that observation such as `detail1`, `detail2`, `detail3`, etc., you can combine them the same way as above: `label <- paste(sep = "<br/>", detail1, 
 detail2,  detail3)`.

Comment: Also, you should probably have a single observation for each lat/long coordinate unless there's a specific reason you want to have duplicate coordinates. I don't really understand that part of your question.

Comment: I updated my question based on your feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially [@Erin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46477942/13110995)'s answer with one change. I think the task can be accomplished with `paste0` which offers an advantage over various other possible methods that involve use of some flavor of `sep= "<br>"`. With `paste0` one has more control over where `<br>` tags are placed. Here two items are joined and then broken so that numbers are named in the popup. For additional styling use HTML tags in the `paste0` call.

```
# Make sample dataframe
long <- c(147.5, 147.5, 147.5, 147, 147)
lat <- c(-36.5, -36.5, -36.5, -36, -36)
label <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)

markers <- data.frame(lat,long,label)

# Paste0 Method
# This has the advantage of controlling where the breaks go.
markers$label <- paste0("Longitude: ", long,"<br>",
                         "Latitude: ",lat, "<br>",
                         "Label: ",label)

# Markers with all of the labels
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  addMarkers(lng=markers$long, lat= markers$lat, 
             popup= markers$label)
```

[image]