# Joining two dataframes by concatenating columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes with the same structure - both have two ID columns and 25 string data columns. I want to join the two and concatenate the strings in the data columns when the IDs match. So, for example:

df_1:

```
id_1    id_2    col_1    col2    ...    col_25
a1      b1      A        A       ...    <NA>
a1      b2      A        <NA>    ...    A
a2      b1      <NA>     <NA>    ...    A
```

df_2:

```
id_1    id_2    col_1    col2    ...    col_25
a1      b1      B        <NA>    ...    <NA>
a1      b2      <NA>     B       ...    B
a1      b3      B        <NA>    ...    B
```

Combined, this should give

df_combined:

```
id_1    id_2    col_1    col2    ...    col_25
a1      b1      A, B     A       ...    <NA>
a1      b2      A        B       ...    A, B
a1      b3      B        <NA>    ...    B
a2      b1      <NA>     <NA>    ...    A
```

When I try to use join or merge, it repeats everything except the ID columns (so I end up with 50 data columns). Do I need to use something else?

Thanks!

Comment: rbind 2 dataframes, then group by ids, loop through columns and paste. See this post for [group by paste for one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958)

Comment: if you provide "ready to use data" ppl would love to help you. Even though the question is very clear. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this if you don't have any empty string :

```
library(dplyr)    
bind_rows(df_1,df_2) %>%
  group_by(id_1,id_2) %>%
  summarize_all(~ paste(na.omit(.x),collapse=", ")) %>%
  `[<-`(.=="",value=NA)
```

with `magrittr` you can avoid the not so pretty `'[<-'` and replace it by `inset`

```
library(magrittr)
bind_rows(df_1,df_2) %>%
  group_by(id_1,id_2) %>%
  summarize_all(~ paste(na.omit(.x),collapse=", ")) %>%
  inset(.=="",value=NA)
```

Comment: Nice 1 for `inset`. I was not aware of that function! Looks handy!

Comment: ooops, I just removed it to avoid magrittr :), i'll put it back as alternate solution

Comment: hehe. Yes, you should keep it in there :)

Comment: I think `ifelse` is a often overused when `inset` would be the logical thing to do, so some publicity won't hurt

Comment: I hate `ifelse`. I try to avoid it as much as possible (hence my preference on `replace`)

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative solution using `melt()` and `dcast()` to reshape the data:

```
library(data.table)
rbind(setDT(df_1), setDT(df_2))[
  , melt(.SD, measure.var = patterns("col"), na.rm = TRUE)][
    , dcast(.SD, id_1 + id_2 ~ variable, toString, fill = NA)]
```

> ```
>    id_1 id_2 col_1 col2 col_25
> 1:   a1   b1  A, B    A     NA
> 2:   a1   b2     A    B   A, B
> 3:   a1   b3     B   NA      B
> 4:   a2   b1    NA   NA      A
> ```

#### Data

```
df_1 <- fread(
  "id_1    id_2    col_1    col2    ...    col_25
a1      b1      A        A       ...    <NA>
a1      b2      A        <NA>    ...    A
a2      b1      <NA>     <NA>    ...    A",
  drop = 5L, na.strings = "<NA>"
)

df_2 <- fread(
  "id_1    id_2    col_1    col2    ...    col_25
a1      b1      B        <NA>    ...    <NA>
a1      b2      <NA>     B       ...    B
a1      b3      B        <NA>    ...    B",
  drop = 5L, na.strings = "<NA>"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate to the idea commented by @zx8754, and using `dplyr` package,

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
 bind_rows(df2) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-contains('id')), funs(replace(., is.na(.), ''))) %>% 
 group_by(id_1, id_2) %>% 
 summarise_all(funs(trimws(paste(., collapse = ' ')))) %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(replace(., . == '', NA)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 5
> # Groups:   id_1 [2]
>    id_1  id_2 col_1  col2 col_25
>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
> 1    a1    b1   A B     A   <NA>
> 2    a1    b2     A     B    A B
> 3    a1    b3     B  <NA>      B
> 4    a2    b1  <NA>  <NA>      A
> ```

**NOTE:**

1. Above script assumes that your NAs are actual `NA` (not characters)
2. Your variables are `as.character`

**DATA**

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(id_1 = c("a1", "a1", "a2"), id_2 = c("b1", "b2", 
"b1"), col_1 = c("A", "A", NA), col2 = c("A", NA, NA), col_25 = c(NA, 
"A", "A")), .Names = c("id_1", "id_2", "col_1", "col2", "col_25"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(df2)
structure(list(id_1 = c("a1", "a1", "a1"), id_2 = c("b1", "b2", 
"b3"), col_1 = c("B", NA, "B"), col2 = c(NA, "B", NA), col_25 = c(NA, 
"B", "B")), .Names = c("id_1", "id_2", "col_1", "col2", "col_25"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```