# Reduce data frame where only one column varies in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data like:

```
    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
1   A     5.7    f    n     j47
2   A     5.7    f    n     j44
3   A     5.7    f    n     e54
4   B     5.1    m    y     j47
5   B     5.1    m    y     r10
```

I want my output to like like:

```
1:    A    5.7    f    n    j47, j44, e54
2;    B    5.1    m    y    j47, r10
```

ie only v5 vaires but I want to collapse my data so that all values for V5 for each identifier (given in V1) can be seen.

How can I do this?

Comment: `df %>% group_by_at(vars(V1:V4)) %>% summarise_all(toString)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w)

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using base R's `aggregate` (no additional libraries necessary):

```
aggregate(data = df, V5 ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4, paste, collapse = ", ")
#  V1  V2 V3 V4            V5
#1  A 5.7  f  n j47, j44, e54
#2  B 5.1  m  y      j47, r10
```

---

### Data

```
df <- read.table(text = 
    "V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
     1   A     5.7    f    n     j47
     2   A     5.7    f    n     j44
     3   A     5.7    f    n     e54
     4   B     5.1    m    y     j47
     5   B     5.1    m    y     r10", header = T)
```

Comment: Unless you add a `collapse` parameter, it's adding a list column. That could be good, but it's not obvious.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for point that out. I've updated my solution to output a plain `dataframe`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr` which is also part of the `tidyverse` along with `dplyr`: (*Edit* Note this adds a list column rather than collapsing V5 into a single string for each group)

```r
library(tidyr)

nest(df, V5)    
#>   V1  V2 V3 V4          data
#> 1  A 5.7  f  n j47, j44, e54
#> 2  B 5.1  m  y      j47, r10
```

**Data used**

```r
df <- (read.table(text = "V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
1   A     5.7    f    n     j47
2   A     5.7    f    n     j44
3   A     5.7    f    n     e54
4   B     5.1    m    y     j47
5   B     5.1    m    y     r10", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Comment: This is pretty neat but it removes the letters (which are icd10 codes, hence critical)

Comment: @SamLipworth, I'm not quite sure what you mean by the letters being removed. Expanding my answer above to `library(tidyverse); nest(df, V5, .key = "V5") %>% mutate(V5 = map_chr(V5, ~ paste0(.$V5, collapse = ", ")))` should give you an answer equivalent to the other answers provided (although not as elegantly!). I hope this helps