# summarizing categorical data in a data frame by pasting ratio numbers

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a categorical covariate data summary as below:

```
 df <- 
 STUDY   COV   FLAG   Freq
 1       SEX   1       12
 1       SEX   2       15
 2       RACE  1       5
 2       RACE  2       10
 2       RACE  3       15
```

I want to make a summary by `STUDY` and `COV` to facilitate generating an rtf table. This the output that i would like to have is this.

```
 dfout <-
 STUDY   COV   RATIO
 1       SEX   12:15
 2       RACE  5:10:15
```

I tried using this but i know it is getting no where

```
  library(dplyr)
  dfout<- df%>% 
    group_by(STUDY,COV) %>% 
    summarise(RATIO=paste(Freq,":",lag(Freq)))
```

i am using Rstudio.

Comment: `df%>%  group_by(STUDY,COV) %>% summarise(RATIO = paste(Freq, collapse = ":"))` will do. It seems that you are a bit thinking too much, perhaps?

Comment: thanks, that worked!

Comment: Perhaps your question is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `lag`, `paste` with `collapse` parameter should do:

```
df%>% 
    group_by(STUDY, COV) %>% 
    summarise(RATIO = paste(Freq, collapse=":"))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups: STUDY [?]
#  STUDY COV    RATIO  
#  <int> <fctr> <chr>  
#1     1 SEX    12:15  
#2     2 RACE   5:10:15
```