# Select from data table as list in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to select a list from a data table and apply a function.
Finally I want the result as a column of the data table..
Following is an example of what i am trying to do ...

I tried something like this :

```
dt <- dt[, value:=f(V3) , by=list(V1)]
```

Data table:

```
V1 V2 V3
1  8  40
1  5  22
1  6  36
2  7  11
2  3  8
2  6  20
2  9  18
3  .  .
.  .  .
```

Result :

```
V1 Value
1  f(list(40,22,36))
2  f(list(11,8,20,18))
3  f(list(...))
```

Comment: Write `?apply` in the r console.

Comment: On my phone here, but something like `apply(data$V3,  f)` should work.

Comment: If the `f` is taking argument as a `list`, then `dt[, .(value = f(list(V3))), V1]` and if you need as a column `dt[, value := f(list(V3)), V1]`

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [*Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15933958/2204410)

Comment: @akrun Thank you, your suggestions worked well :)