# How can I summarize rows for unique value of two columns

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a rowsum in a df as in example:

```
df1
Name    Ch1    Val1
A        a     x1
A        a     x2
A        b     x3
B        c     x4
B        c     x5
B        d     x6
...
```

to

```
df2
Name    Ch1    Val1
A        a     x1+x2
A        b     x3
B        c     x4+x5
B        d     x6
...
```

I want to get the rowsum of Val1 (numeric!) where Ch1 (character) is unique according to Name (character)!
I know I can join Name and Ch1 then do rowsum and then spread it again but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: So just group by the first 2 columns and take a summary stat (in this case sum)? There should be a lot of SO posts on this already; [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15933958/5325862) that links to plenty others. If these values are intended to be numeric, it's helpful for your example to reflect that

Comment: Maybe `aggregate(VAL1 ~ Name + CH1, df1, sum)` ?

Comment: no because this only refers to one variable. I am struggeling with summing it according to two groups.

Comment: Several of the answers there deal with grouping by multiple columns, and others would be trivial to expand from one column to 2. Searching the R tag for ["is:question calculate sum by group"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+is%3Aquestion+calculate+sum+by+group) gets dozens of contenders

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to group by both 'Name', 'Ch1', and `paste` the 'Val1' column values

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name, Ch1) %>%
   summarise(Val1 = str_c(Val1, collapse="+"))
```

Comment: Error is: group_by - function not found

Comment: @antonina Sorrry, forgot to add the package.  Updated

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution

```
library('data.table')

# Data
df1 <- fread('Name    Ch1    Val1
             A        a     x1
             A        a     x2
             A        b     x3
             B        c     x4
             B        c     x5
             B        d     x6')

# for demonstration purpose, assign some values to Val2
df1[, Val2 := 1:.N]
df1
#    Name Ch1 Val1 Val2
# 1:    A   a   x1    1
# 2:    A   a   x2    2
# 3:    A   b   x3    3
# 4:    B   c   x4    4
# 5:    B   c   x5    5
# 6:    B   d   x6    6

df1[, .(Val2 = sum(Val2)), by = .(Name, Ch1)]
#    Name Ch1 Val2
# 1:    A   a    3
# 2:    A   b    3
# 3:    B   c    9
# 4:    B   d    6
```