# How to keep all columns when concatenating rows with dplyr::summarise?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to aggregate one column (`C`) in a data frame according to one grouping variable `A`, and separate the individual values by a comma while keeping all the other column `B`. However, `B` can either have a character (which is always the same for all the rows) or be empty. In this case, I would like to keep the character whenever it is present on one row.

Here is a simplified example:

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(rep(111, 3), rep(222, 3)), B = c("", "", "", "a" , "", "a"), C = c(5:10))
data
```

Based on this question [Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w), I have the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(test = toString(C)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Here it is what I would like to obtain:

```
    A B  C
1 111    5,6,7
2 222 a  8,9,10
```

Comment: It is keeping also the B column. Can you provide the expected results?

Comment: I realised that my question was way too simplified. I've edited accordingly to make it more clear. Sorry to all for my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write one function to return unique values

```
library(dplyr)

get_common_vars <- function(x) {
   if(n_distinct(x) > 1) unique(x[x !='']) else unique(x)
}
```

and then use it on all columns that you are interested :

```
data %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(C = toString(C)) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(B:C), get_common_vars)
  #                  ^------ Include all columns here

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#     A  B     C       
#  <dbl> <fct> <chr>   
#1   111 ""    5, 6, 7 
#2   222 a     8, 9, 10
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! this does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use summarise_all()

To keep all your columns, you can use `summarise_all()`:

```
data %>% 
    group_by(A) %>% 
    summarise_all(toString)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
      A B       C       
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
1   111 1, 2, 1 5, 6, 7 
2   222 2, 1, 2 8, 9, 10
```

### Edit for updated question

You can add a B column to `summarise` to achieve the desided results:

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(rep(111, 3), rep(222, 3)), B = c("", "", "", "a" , "", "a"), C = c(5:10))
data

library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(B = names(sort(table(B),decreasing=TRUE))[1], 
            C = toString(C)) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      A B     C       
  <dbl> <fct> <chr>   
1   111 ""    5, 6, 7 
2   222 a     8, 9, 10
```

This will return the most frequent value in B column (as `order` gives you ordered indexes).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fully work. The column `B` of the 2nd row is empty instead of `a`

Comment: @Euclides Yes, there was an error in the previous code. I've tested this and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `paste()` function and leverage the `collapse` argument.

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(
    B = paste(unique(B), collapse = ""),
    C = paste(C, collapse = ", "))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  A     B     C       
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   
1 111   ""    5, 6, 7 
2 222   a     8, 9, 10
```