# R - Comma delimit a column while adding others

Tags: r, format, data-cleaning

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
ID    Age
1     19
2     20
3     56
4     81
```

I want to add up the column age and comma delimit ID:

```
ID         Age
1,2,3,4    176
```

I have tried this:

`aggregate(ID ~., data, toString)` as per this solution:

[Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w)

But, this is not producing desired result.

Comment: How would `aggregate` *know* that you wanted to sum `Age`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a new data frame by applying different functions to each column.

```
#Your data
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4),
                 Age = c(19,20,56,81))
#Output
resul <- data.frame(ID = paste(df$ID, collapse = ","),
                    Age = sum(df$Age))

#       ID Age
#1 1,2,3,4 176
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(ID = toString(ID), Age = sum(Age))

#          ID Age
#1 1, 2, 3, 4 176
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(ID = toString(ID), Age = sum(Age))]
```