# How can I combine the same line numbers? in R

Tags: r, dataframe, nested, rbind

There is a data frame fragmented with "unnest_tokens" and with stopwords removed. I want to reassemble this data frame. I want to add the "Line" column of the same value in a single row. I tried several suggestions, but it didn't. How can I do that?

The data frame is as follows.

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0" class="tg"><thead><tr><th style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">line</th><th style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">word</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">hello</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">and</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">so</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">and</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">deneme</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">cat</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">car</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">best</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">apple</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">engine</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">stack</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">overflow</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">tree</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">bus</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">golden</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Name of the data frame: *text_parcali_normal*

```
nested_data<-text_parcali_normal %>%group_by(line)
```

The output(nested_data) I expected is as follows.

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0" class="tg"><thead><tr><th style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">line</th><th style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">word</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">hello and so tree bus</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">and cat car golden</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">deneme best stack overflow</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">apple engine</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Add data using `dput` or `data.frame(line = c(....), word = c(....))` No need to add it in HTML for `R`. Perhaps, you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w ?

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. I used HTML codes to show the tables. I am thinking of doing as you say next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `summarise` with `paste`:

```
nested_data <- text_parcali_normal %>%
  group_by(line) %>%
  summarise(word = paste(word, collapse = " "))
```