# Convert column into a sequence

Tags: r, data-conversion, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

| name | sex |
| --- | --- |
| ab | f |
| ab | m |
| ab | f |
| bc | f |
| bc | f |
| bc | m |

I want to convert the observations of the column 'sex' as string. The outcome should look like:

| name | seq |
| --- | --- |
| ab | fmf |
| bc | ffm |

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Related: [Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(sex = paste(sex, collapse = "")) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name  sex  
  <chr> <chr>
1 ab    fmf  
2 bc    ffm
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("ab", "ab", "ab", "bc", "bc", "bc"), 
               sex = c("f", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(sex ~ ., df, paste0, collapse = "")
  name sex
1   ab fmf
2   bc ffm
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(name = c("ab", "ab", "ab", "bc", "bc", "bc"), 
    sex = c("f", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

**data.table**

```
setDT(df)[, list(sex = paste0(sex, collapse = "")), by = name]

   name sex
1:   ab fmf
2:   bc ffm
```