# How to merge the rows of a tibble to collapse cells into a single one

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a tibble with a thousand something rows, and two columns, the first of which contains a categorical label, and the second a character string. Here is a MRE

```
tab <- tibble(category = c("CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT2", "CAT2", "CAT2"),
              word = c("Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "Consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "nam"))
tab

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  category word       
  <chr>    <chr>      
1 CAT1     Lorem      
2 CAT1     ipsum      
3 CAT1     dolor      
4 CAT1     sit        
5 CAT1     amet       
6 CAT2     Consectetur
7 CAT2     adipiscing 
8 CAT2     elit       
9 CAT2     nam
```

Now, what I'd like to do is to collapse these rows in order to have only one row per `category` and all the `words` for that category together in a single cell, separated by a semi-colon. Like that:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  category word                              
  <chr>    <chr>                             
1 CAT1     Lorem; ipsum; dolor; sit; amet    
2 CAT2     Consectetur; adipiscing; elit; nam
```

Does anyone know how I could tackle this issue and is willing to fly my rescue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tab %>%
    group_by(category) %>%
    summarise(word = str_c(word, collapse ="; "))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  category word                              
  <chr>    <chr>                             
1 CAT1     Lorem; ipsum; dolor; sit; amet    
2 CAT2     Consectetur; adipiscing; elit; nam
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also `pivot_wider`,  then `unite` the desired columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tab %>% pivot_wider(names_from = word, values_from = word) %>%
        unite(col='word', -category, sep=', ', na.rm = TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  category word                              
  <chr>    <chr>                             
1 CAT1     Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet    
2 CAT2     Consectetur, adipiscing, elit, nam
```