# Creating a Transaction Vector for Use in Arules (R)

Tags: r, data-mining, arules

[image: Hi, I'm trying to create a vector like what I have drawn. A single vector that has entries corresponding to a transaction. Each Item Description belongs to a given Bill Number. I'm trying to essentially have a mapping from Bill Number to Item Desc in a one, to one fashion. My end goal is to feed this vector through arules apriori algorithm to recommend items. Thank you so much!]

Hi, I'm trying to create a vector like what I have drawn. A single vector that has entries corresponding to a transaction. Each Item Description belongs to a given Bill Number. I'm trying to essentially have a mapping from Bill Number to Item Desc in a one, to one fashion. My end goal is to feed this vector through arules apriori algorithm to recommend items. Thank you so much!

Edit: dput(cafe)

```
dput(cafe)

cafe %>%
group_by(`Bill Number`) %>%
select(`Bill Number`, `Item Desc`)
```

Output

```
 # A tibble: 145,830 x 2
# Groups:   Bill Number [69,982]
   `Bill Number` `Item Desc`             
   <fct>         <fct>                   
 1 G0470115      MINERAL WATER(1000ML)   
 2 G0470115      MONSOON MALABAR (AULAIT)
 3 G0470116      MASALA CHAI CUTTING     
 4 G0470117      MINERAL WATER(1000ML)   
 5 G0470283      MOROCCAN MINT TEA       
 6 G0470283      MINERAL WATER(1000ML)   
 7 G0470118      MASALA CHAI CUTTING     
 8 G0470118      MOROCCAN MINT TEA       
 9 G0470284      CAPPUCCINO              
10 G0470285      MOROCCAN MINT TEA
```

Essentially all I'm trying to do is make a list where each entry corresponds to a unique `Bill Number` and contains all those `Item Desc` that belong to it.

For example in my code below notice that Bill Number `G0470115`
corresponds to two different `Item Desc`. I want to take both of those `Item Desc` and put them in an entry in a list. So that entry in the list corresponds to that specific `Bill Number`. And basically I need to repeat this for all `Bill Number`.

Comment: Your data (structure) and problem description is not clear to me. Please include sample data in a reproducible "copy & paste"-able format (using e.g. `dput`); don't include data as a screenshot as we cannot (easily) extract data from an image. I recommend showing minimal & representative sample data and your corresponding expected output along with what you're trying to do. That will give us something to work with.

Comment: Thank you Maurits, is what I posted sufficient now?

Comment: Likely duplicate: [Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w)