# R: Concatenate strings from one column based on repeating strings in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, stringr

I have a data frame that looks like the example below.

| element | string |
| --- | --- |
| x | abc |
| y | def |
| z | ghi |
| z | jkl |
| x | mno |
| y | pqr |
| z | stu |
| x | vwx |
| y | yza |
| z | bcd |
| z | efg |
| z | hij |
| x | klm |
| y | nop |
| z | qrs |
| z | tuv |
| z | wxy |

All the strings in the string column vary but the values in the element column always follow an x-y-z pattern, although the number of z's varies. I would like to take the strings in the strings column from each x-y-z set and concatenate them - so the strings column in the dataframe above would look like this:

| string |
| --- |
| abc def ghi jkl |
| mno pqr stu |
| vwx yza bcd efg hij |
| klm nop qrs tuv wxy |

I was thinking there might be a way to do this using dplyr::rowwise?  The variable # of z rows per each set is tripping me up though in figuring out something that might work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w, where your group is `cumsum(element == "x")`.

Comment: @Henrik That worked beautifully, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part is that you need to group by chunks of x/y/z. Below is one approach. Once you have your id to group by you can simply summarize and concatenate the strings.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(element = c(letters[24:26], 'z', letters[24:26]),
                 string = c('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'ijk', 'lmn', 'o', 'p'))

df %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(if_else(element < lag(element), 1, 0, missing = 1))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(strong = str_c(string, collapse = ' '), .groups = 'drop')
```

With the above test data, this gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id strong         
  <dbl> <chr>          
1     1 abc def ghi ijk
2     2 lmn o p
```